# HP SNMP Traps signalled every 10 seconds for a NIC

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, snmp, alerts

I'm trying to setup SNMP traps on my HP DL160 G6 (Xenserver) to notify me whenever I have issues with the server.

Following suggestions from [this serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/a/342392/143027), I've installed the HP SNMP agents and configured my `cma.conf` to email me whenever I have an SNMP trap generated.  To test it out, I unplugged a secondary NIC.

My problem is that instead of just getting a single trap indicating that the NIC was disconnected or reconnected, I get traps generated every 10secs indicating that the link is down or up.

I also installed the HP System Management web interface, but can't seem to find how to configure the NIC agent to stop sending traps every 10secs and only trap on state change.

Is this possible?

With the SNMP agent (cmanicd) enabled, I get the following in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Feb 28 16:51:01 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: 192.168.0.152: Enterprise Specific Trap (18012)
Feb 28 16:51:01 xenserver-opvorsfu logger:  Uptime: 4:32:23.51
Feb 28 16:51:01 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: xenserver-opvorsfu
Feb 28 16:51:01 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.11.2.11.1.0 = INTEGER: 0
Feb 28 16:51:01 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.18.2.3.1.1.5.2 = INTEGER: 0
Feb 28 16:51:01 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.18.2.3.1.1.10.2 = INTEGER: 2
Feb 28 16:51:01 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.2.2.4.17.0 = STRING: "Not Available"
Feb 28 16:51:01 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.18.2.3.1.1.14.2 = INTEGER: 4
Feb 28 16:51:01 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.1.2.13.1.1.5.5.0 = STRING: "HP NC362i Integrated DP Gigabit Server Adapter"
Feb 28 16:51:01 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.18.2.3.1.1.32.2 = ""
Feb 28 16:51:01 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: IP-MIB::ipAdEntAddr.0.0.0.0 = IpAddress: 0.0.0.0
Feb 28 16:51:01 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.18.2.4.1.1.6.2 = STRING: "N/A"
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu cmanicd: Entering iml_log_link_down(slot: 0, port: 2) 
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu cmanicd: Entering log_iml_event(slot: 0, port: 2, code: (Down,2)) 
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu cmanicd: Entering get_event_id(slot: 0, port: 2 
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu cmanicd: No Existing event id found for the slot and port. 
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu cmanicd: an IML entry for this slot and port does not exist, so add one. 
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu cmanicd: cmanic: could not log IML event, retval = 4 errno = 0, logevt.c,774  
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:51:01 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:50:51 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:50:40 xenserver-o
pvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:50:40 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:50:39 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:50:29 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:5
0:19 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:50:08 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:49:58 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:49:57 xenserver-opvorsfu log
ger: Feb 28 16:49:54 xenserver-opvorsfu kernel: [16281.101268] igb: eth1 NIC Link is Down
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: 192.168.0.152: Enterprise Specific Trap (18012)
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu logger:  Uptime: 4:32:33.98
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: xenserver-opvorsfu
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.11.2.11.1.0 = INTEGER: 0
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.18.2.3.1.1.5.2 = INTEGER: 0
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.18.2.3.1.1.10.2 = INTEGER: 2
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.2.2.4.17.0 = STRING: "Not Available"
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.18.2.3.1.1.14.2 = INTEGER: 4
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.1.2.13.1.1.5.5.0 = STRING: "HP NC362i Integrated DP Gigabit Server Adapter"
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.18.2.3.1.1.32.2 = ""
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: IP-MIB::ipAdEntAddr.0.0.0.0 = IpAddress: 0.0.0.0
Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.18.2.4.1.1.6.2 = STRING: "N/A"
Feb 28 16:51:15 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:52919 
Feb 28 16:51:15 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:32864 
Feb 28 16:51:15 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:51237 
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu cmanicd: Entering iml_log_link_down(slot: 0, port: 2) 
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu cmanicd: Entering log_iml_event(slot: 0, port: 2, code: (Down,2)) 
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu cmanicd: Entering get_event_id(slot: 0, port: 2 
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu cmanicd: No Existing event id found for the slot and port. 
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu cmanicd: an IML entry for this slot and port does not exist, so add one. 
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu cmanicd: cmanic: could not log IML event, retval = 4 errno = 0, logevt.c,774  
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:51:12 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:51:01 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:50:51 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:50:40 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:50:40 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:50:39 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:50:29 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:50:19 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:50:08 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:49:58 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:49:57 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: Feb 28 16:49:54 xenserver-opvorsfu kernel: [16281.101268] igb: eth1 NIC Link is Down
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: 192.168.0.152: Enterprise Specific Trap (18012)
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu logger:  Uptime: 4:32:44.43
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: xenserver-opvorsfu
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.11.2.11.1.0 = INTEGER: 0
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.18.2.3.1.1.5.2 = INTEGER: 0
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.18.2.3.1.1.10.2 = INTEGER: 2
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.2.2.4.17.0 = STRING: "Not Available"
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.18.2.3.1.1.14.2 = INTEGER: 4
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.1.2.13.1.1.5.5.0 = STRING: "HP NC362i Integrated DP Gigabit Server Adapter"
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.18.2.3.1.1.32.2 = ""
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: IP-MIB::ipAdEntAddr.0.0.0.0 = IpAddress: 0.0.0.0
Feb 28 16:51:22 xenserver-opvorsfu logger: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.18.2.4.1.1.6.2 = STRING: "N/A"
Feb 28 16:51:30 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:41836 
Feb 28 16:51:30 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:50204 
Feb 28 16:51:30 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:47990 
Feb 28 16:51:32 xenserver-opvorsfu cmanicd: Entering iml_log_link_down(slot: 0, port: 2)
```

With `cmanicd` disabled, I get the following in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Feb 28 16:44:28 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:55759 
Feb 28 16:44:28 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:33561 
Feb 28 16:44:28 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:48321 
Feb 28 16:44:32 xenserver-opvorsfu kernel: [15959.771627] igb: eth1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
Feb 28 16:44:43 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:52043 
Feb 28 16:44:43 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:52082 
Feb 28 16:44:43 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:46917 
Feb 28 16:44:58 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:42179 
Feb 28 16:44:58 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:56542 
Feb 28 16:44:58 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:52481 
Feb 28 16:45:09 xenserver-opvorsfu kernel: [15996.671268] igb: eth1 NIC Link is Down
Feb 28 16:45:14 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:58277 
Feb 28 16:45:14 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:57163 
Feb 28 16:45:14 xenserver-opvorsfu snmpd[19168]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:58464
```

Comment: Do you see corresponding messages in `/var/log/messages`?

Comment: If I disable the SNMP NIC agent, I get a single log that the NIC link is up when I plug it in and a single log entry that the link is down when I unplug it.  But when I have the SNMP agent enabled, and I unplug/replug the NIC, I get tons of entries in my /var/log/messages file (see updated question)